# how to obtain quanteda package's fcm to sub-matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, nlp, igraph, quanteda

I have a fcm object of quanteda package in R which I used for calculating the co-occurrences. This matrix is 110518 x 110518. Now, I want to subset my matrix for 50 words that I obtained from my analysis. I want to end up with 50x50 co-occurrence matrix and create an igraph object. I tried the code below from a stackoverflow post

```
 fcm_sub <- fcm[, c("words x 50 here")]
```

However, it ended up with 110518 x 50 sub-matrix. I tried to use `fcm_select` option too. At this time, It loses all weights for co-occurrences and seems like 0x0. How can I obtain exact features with 50x50 sub-matrix?

Answer (score 2):

You are only selecting one part of the matrix, the columns. You still get all the rows.

```
library(quanteda)

txt3 <- c("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
          "The dog jumped and ate the fox.")
toks3 <- tokens(char_tolower(txt3), remove_punct = TRUE)
my_fcm <- fcm(toks3, context = "document")

my_fcm[,c("fox", "dog")]
Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 10 by 2 features.
        features
features fox dog
  the      4   4
  quick    1   1
  brown    1   1
  fox      0   2
  jumped   0   2
  over     0   1
  lazy     0   1
  dog      0   0
  and      0   0
  ate      0   0
```

What you need to do is use your selection on both columns and rows:

```
my_fcm[c("fox", "dog"), c("fox", "dog")]
Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 2 by 2 features.
        features
features fox dog
     fox   0   2
     dog   0   0
```

Or as @kenbenoit says, use:

```
fcm_select(my_fcm, c("fox", "dog"))
Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 2 by 2 features.
        features
features fox dog
     fox   0   2
     dog   0   0
```

Comment: An equivalent alternative is `fcm_select(my_fcm, c("fox", "dog"))`.